# React Native - Problem with fetch into a component

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I got a problem I can not understand.

I tried to close the App and Expo in Terminal, launch again.
Search on a Google.
I tried many things, but still I got a strange things.

So, I have a list of items (crypto-asset) and when I select one of them, a new window appears with details of this token. Simple.

Here is my "FlatList" :

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Alert, FlatList, View } from 'react-native'
import { SettingsContext } from '../../contexts/SettingsContext'
import ItemToken from '../ItemToken/ItemToken'

export function TokenList() {
  const { currency } = useContext(SettingsContext)
  const [listToken, setListToken] = useState(null)
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    getListTokens()
  }, [currency])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (refreshing) {
      getListTokens()
      setRefreshing(false)
    }
  }, [refreshing])

  /**
   * For the currency, never mind, it's just Boolean to get things done, it's not the final code.
   */
  function getListTokens() {
    fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=${
      currency ? 'usd' : 'eur'
    }&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setListToken(json))
      .catch(error => Alert.alert('CoinGecko API Error', error))
    }

return (
  <FlatList
    data={listToken}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    onRefresh={() => setRefreshing(true)}
    refreshing={refreshing}
    renderItem={
      ({ item }) =>
        <ItemToken item={item} />
    }
    ItemSeparatorComponent={<View style={{ height: 1, opacity: 0.6 }} />}
  />
  )
}
```

My ItemToken (without CSS) :

```
import { useContext, memo } from 'react'
import { View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { SettingsContext } from '../../contexts/SettingsContext'
import { NavigationContext } from '@react-navigation/native'

function ItemToken({ item }) {
  const { currency } = useContext(SettingsContext)
  const { navigation } = useContext(NavigationContext)

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('StackTokenDetail', { id: [item.id] })}>
      <View>
        <Image style={styles.image} src={item.image} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.mainSection}>
      <Text style={styles.fontStyle}>{item.name}</Text>
      <Text>{currency ? '$' : null}{item.current_price}{currency ? null : '€'}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Ok, this it's ok.

Here my component to display the detail of the token.
It's here where I get my problems.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import TokenDetail from '../../TokenDetail/TokenDetail'

export function StackTokenDetail({ route }) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${route.params.id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setToken(json))
      .catch(e => console.error(e))
  }, [])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, padding: 40 }}>
        <TokenDetail token={token} />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

And my detail stack page:

```
import { memo } from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

function TokenDetail({ token }) {
  console.log('tokenDetail token:', token.name)
  console.log('tokenDetail token:', token.symbol.toUpperCase())
  console.log('tokenDetail token:', token.description.en)

  return (
    <>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 600, paddingBottom: 20 }}>{token.symbol.toUpperCase()} - {token.name}</Text>
      <Text>{token.description.en}</Text>
    </>
  )
}

export default memo(TokenDetail)
```

Well when I start from the list and select an item, I got this error: "Cannot read property 'name' of null.

OK

But, if I delete all lines with the token from JSON in the last component, save and refresh. I select again an item and display the screen. Normal you will say. Right!

But if I put my lines again, save, refresh, then my all console.log will display the informations I get from the server. Everything is here and works. Event the App display the symbol and the name, but not the description (which I got a hours ago).

If I click on the back button, return to the list and select an item (the same one or a different), then crash again...

Please, can you help me to understand?

Also it's why I create a new component for the display the informations and use a memo.

Thank you.

I try to get some data from a server, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because you are dangerously passing the token value at  `<TokenDetail token={token} />` line even though its value is null. At the start of the `TokenList` component, you define state using `const [token, setToken] = useState(null)`. May be you can do two things here to resolve this issue.

**Solution 1:**
Do not show the TokenDetail component till the token value is not null(Which eventually happens after the API call you are making. See the code below

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, padding: 40 }}>
        {token ? <TokenDetail token={token} /> : null}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
)
```

**Solution 2:**
Access the token value inside the TokenDetail in a safe manner using the optional chaining technique.

```
function TokenDetail({ token }) {
  console.log('tokenDetail token:', token?.name)
  console.log('tokenDetail token:', token?.symbol?.toUpperCase())
  console.log('tokenDetail token:', token?.description?.en)

  return (
    <>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 600, paddingBottom: 20 }}>{token ? {{token.symbol.toUpperCase()} - {token.name}} : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{token ? token.description.en : ""}</Text>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I tried something like this, but in a wrong way I think. So I use the first solution and now it's work. BUT, still, I do not have a description in the App. It's display on a Terminal but not on a view. Do you know why please? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah., looks like you are not providing any font details to the Text component( such as font size, colour etc). Could you try it once? And as the main issue is resolved, could you kindly accept& upvote the answer?

Comment: Yeah, style looks like it's work. I can't see the complete text now. I try to found a set of CSS to make it readable. The scrollview don't take all the height on screen.

Comment: Great to hear that the problem is resolved.!